# LateInitializationError: Field 'myfuture' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-test

The issue that I am facing is in future builder in flutter.When opening the page first time the data is loaded successfully but when I go to a different page and then return to the same page it throws an error **LateInitializationError: Field 'myfuture' has not been initialized.**

Hence if you could please help me resolve this issue.

Please find below the code and let me know if any further information is required from my end.

view.dart

```
late final Future myfuture;

@override
  void initState() {
    print('init started'); // on opening second time the process gets stuck here with the above error message
     
    if (Provider.of<FilterOptionProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .initialList
        .isEmpty) {
      myfuture = Provider.of<FilterOptionProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .readfilters(checkfilters);
    }
    super.initState();
}

Widget _buildList() {
    final notificationData =
        Provider.of<FilterOptionProvider>(context, listen: true);
    final ndata = notificationData.initialList;
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: myfuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error occured'),
            );
          } else {
            final notificationData =
                Provider.of<FilterOptionProvider>(context, listen: true);
            final ndata = notificationData.initialList;
```

provider.dart

```
Future<void> readfilters(Map<String, dynamic> queryPam) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-Type": "charset=utf-8",
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    };
```

Comment: prefer nullable property instead of `late` because there is no way to check if `late` property has been initialized.

Comment: how do I make Future myfuture a nullable property.. I tried adding final Future? myfuture but it shows the error it must be initialized

Comment: ok got it just had to make this change(remove late and final before it) : Future? myfuture

Answer (score 0):

Just init the empty future in `else`,

```
if (Provider.of<Filter...) {
  ...
}
else {
  myFuture = Future(() {});
}
```